# Export all texting /messaging data from android to local drive and access them in local computer

Tags: android, sms, database-backups, google-pixel

This seems like a rather simple goal but one that I have no found good options for.

I want to be able to export ALL my messaging texts and any related metadata (timestamps, attached images, etc). I have a Google Pixel and use the google messaging app for texting. How can export this data to my local drive so that I have a local backup (not a google cloud backup) of my texts that I can access/reference/search from my computer?

I have SimpleSSHD to access my phone via SSH.